# How should I retain a pointer to an std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myClass>> vec;
//filling the vector
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass()));
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass()));
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass()));
```

I need a handle to a specific instance of `myClass` that doesn't need to worry about ownership, e.g:

```
std::unique_ptr<myClass>& myInstance;
```

The problem is that `myInstance` will need point to different instances of `myClass` during runtime.

I know I could use an `std::shared_ptr`, but I want to keep them `std::unique_ptr`'s so if something already initialized is added the ownership is transferred to `vec`.

**How should I retain a pointer to an `std::unique_ptr`?**

Additionally, would it considered bad practice to use a raw pointer here? The pointer won't need to manage any resources, but I don't want my code to get confusing.

Comment: The disadvantage of raw pointers is managing memory. If you're not doing that, use them for what their name suggests!

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I get so caught up in "good practice" that I vastly complicate things.

Comment: I've had the same thought process, thinking that smart pointers should be used over every pointer. SO helped me to realize smart pointers are only useful when you involve `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I've thought it might be nice to have some equivalent to a weak_ptr for a unique_ptr, so that if the unique_ptr is deleted, the corresponding weak_ptr would be invalidated.  I imagine this isn't done because it would make the unique_ptr less lightweight.  Maybe it would be good if there was a non_shared_ptr, that was basically the same as a shared_ptr, but didn't allow copying.

Comment: Why do you need an array of pointers at all?  Is this a virtual class?

Comment: The instances of `myClass` are created elsewhere in the code and added to an object with an `std::vector`. I wouldn't want to copy them as `myClass` is a fairly heavyweight class.

Comment: @Rabenholz: if you don't want to copy instances of `myClass` for performance reasons, then your first effort should be to try to make the class efficiently movable. If you can't do that, smart pointers are the next best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments to your post indicate that using a raw pointer in a "non-owning" capacity should be OK. I tend to concur with that general sentiment, but your case needs further examination.

For your situation you should not use "a pointer to an std::unique_ptr". The problem is that when you (or a maintenance programmer) adds to the vector, the vector could reallocate. If it does, your pointer is invalidated and must not be used.

One option would be to use the index into the vector instead of a pointer. This has the problem of breaking if you ever delete or rearrange entries in the vector.

Another, more robust, option is to use a pointer direct to the actual myClass object rather than the unique_ptr that owns it. This option is enabled by your use of a vector of unique_ptrs of objects instead of the more usual vector of objects.